# Adding a constrain on existing table in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table status_borrower which contains fields `borrower_id`, `borrower_status` and `limit`. I have three status types: "teacher", "student" and "other". Teacher can borrow max 3 books, student 2 and other 1. I want to add a constraint that you can't add more then 3 in `limit` if the name is "teacher" more then 2 if the name is "student" and etc. It is really new thing for me and I cannot figure it out. Appreciate some help.
[image]

Comment: You can't handle this with constraints. But you can define triggers that abort the update/insert if too many books are borrowed

Comment: Any suggestions on how to do it with triggers then? I am also interested.

Comment: In the trigger do this: `if (<some conditions that should lead to an abort>) SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'You cannot borrow more books';`

Comment: thanks,  that worked.